# Put a line on zero value of y axis

Tags: core-plot

Helo,

Is it possible to put a line on zero value of y axis ?

Because i have negatives values so i changed orthogonal value of my axis to the lowest one on my datasource.

Thanks

[image: graph]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make second x-axis and position it at zero. You can leave off the labels and tick marks to just get the axis line. See the axis demo in the *Plot Gallery* app for an example of how to add additional axes to a Core Plot graph.